# How to make the File upload mandatory once the stage is changed to Closed Won on the Opportunity

Tags: trigger

I need to create a trigger on Opportunity, such that when stage changes to Closed as Won, it throws an error saying you need to upload the attachment before moving it to Closed as Won. I have below trigger, however, it fails because error is thrown even after I have uploaded the attachment.

```
trigger closeWonMustAttach on Opportunity (before insert, before update) {



  Map<Id,Opportunity> opportunityAttachments = new Map<Id,Opportunity>(

    [SELECT Id,(SELECT Id FROM Attachments) FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN :Trigger.new]

  );



  for(Opportunity opp:Trigger.new) {

      if(opp.StageName=='Closed Won'&&

      (!opportunityAttachments.containsKey(opp.id) || 

       opportunityAttachments.get(opp.id).Attachments == null ||

       opportunityAttachments.get(opp.id).Attachments.size()==0))
      opp.StageName.addError('You must first attach a file to this opportunity before changing to Closed/Won.');

    }

  }
```

Comment: Are you uploading Classic Attachments or Lightning Files? They are different sObjects.

Comment: I am uploading Lightning files.

Answer (score 1):

Lightning Files are not represented as Attachments, which is used for Classic Files. Lightning Files use the [Content](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_content.htm) object system (`ContentDocument`, `ContentVersion`, and `ContentDocumentLink`).

You can query these using the child relationship name `AttachedContentDocuments`, which is a list of `ContentDocumentLink` records.